# Error trying to use storedprocedure in Spring

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, jdbc

```
<bean id="storedProcedure" class="org.uftwf.disasterreliefbatch.storedprocedure.DRAMXFR">   </bean>
```

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Property 'sql' is required

Comment: you have more of a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?32643-sql-is-required-problem

Answer (score 0):

I have a java class that extends the spring stored procedure. I was building with Maven, and deploying the ear to WebLogic.
Upon deployment, WebLogic would throw this exception:

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
Property 'dataSource' is required

Since I had the dataSource as a class constructor argument, I resolved the issue by removing the setter method (setDataSource) from the stored proc class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

```
<context:component-scan base-package="packageName"/>
```

You should remove @Component from org.uftwf.disasterreliefbatch.storedprocedure.DRAMXFR